# How to restrict style to only part of HTML

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

Consider:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table, td, th
    {
        border: 1px solid green;
    }

    th
    {
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```

I want to apply this to only a single table in an HTML page which has other tables as well. I don't want to use this style for those tables.

Can we really do what I am asking?

Comment: "...to only single table in an html page which have other tables also..." Do you have a table with inner tables, or a html with several tables?

Comment: @IntoTheVoid : no not inner tables. Only simple tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table.myTable
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table.myTable, table.myTable td, table.myTable th
    {
        border: 1px solid green;
    }

    table.myTable th
    {
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```

And then change that table to have a class attribute like this:

```
<table class="myTable">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class and use it for the table you want the styles to work on:

```css
table.myStyles
{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

table.myStyles, .myStyles td, .myStyles th
{
    border:1px solid green;
}

.myStyles th
{
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
}
```

Then for your table

```
<table class="myStyles">....</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do one of the following:

- modify the table's html to give the `table` and `ID` or a `class`, then modify your CSS to `table.foo`
- target the table only if it is the first or the last table inside a container using `:first-child`, `:last-child`

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
  .green-table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
  }
  .green-table td, .green-table th {
    border:1px solid green;
  }
  .green-table th {
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
  }
</style>

<table class="green-table">
    ...
</table>
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score -1):

This is quite easy to do.  Just give the table an id, and reference that idea using the '#' in your css code.